# Ошибка "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом"

Tags: windows, процесс

хочу залить на гитхаб свою папочку, но когда я нажимаю commit он мне выдает ошибку:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: Could not open 'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Лабы/Labs_2016/Lab_4/Lab_4.VC.VC.opendb': Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.

Вроде бы у меня ничего кроме visual studio не запущено и код закрыт. Но ошибку выдает. Так вот где я накосячил и как это исправить?

Comment: Скачайте [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), в ней вбейте имя файла и посмотрите, кто его держит.

Comment: Закрой торрент, частая ошибка))!

Answer (score 3):

Видимо, какой-то процесс держит этот файл открытым.

Чтобы найти этот процесс, скачайте [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), в ней вбейте имя файла.

(ответ на основе комментария [andreycha](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/106/andreycha))

Comment: У sysinternals же есть более специализированная утилита: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle